# Serialize JSON from Web service in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, json, web-services, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to serialize the result of a web service call, but when I use string result form web service it doesn't work, however, if I use a string with same content it works.

This is the code I use to call the webservice:

```
 var client = new HttpClient();
 var response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(url));
 string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Result string is this Json:

```
{"aa":[{"ts":"2015-01-18 21:00","bb":33783,"cc":7106,"dd":0,"ee":6775,"ff":3319,"gg":6112,"hh":6344,"ii":3703,"jj":581,"kk":-232,"ll":66},{"ts":"2015-01-18 21:10","bb":34263,"cc":7105,"dd":0,"ee":6750,"ff":3327,"gg":6224,"hh":6228,"ii":3690,"jj":1101,"kk":-232,"ll":65}]}
```

And these are the class I've used to serialize:

```
[DataContract]
public class JsonClass{
    [DataMember]
    public List<aaDetails> aa{ get; set; }

}

 [DataContract]
public class aaDetails{
    [DataMember]
    public string ts { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int? bb{ get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int? cc{ get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int? dd{ get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int? ee{ get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int? ff{ get; set; }
    [DataMember] 
  public int? gg{ get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int? hh{ get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int? i{ get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int? jj{ get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int? kk{ get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int? ll{ get; set; }
    }
```

If I tried to use the string result from web service, it doesn't work, data is NULL:

```
DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(JsonClass));

 MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result));
 JsonClass data= (JsonClass)serializer.ReadObject(memStream);
```

If I put a string with the same content and I use it, it works (data has all elements):

```
result = @"{""aa"":[{""ts"":""2015-01-18 21:00"",""bb"":33783,""cc"":7106,""dd"":0,""ee"":6775,""ff"":3319,""gg"":6112,""hh"":6344,""ii"":3703,""jj"":581,""kk"":-232,""ll"":66},{""ts"":""2015-01-18 21:10"",""bb"":34263,""cc"":7105,""dd"":0,""ee"":6750,""ff"":3327,""gg"":6224,""hh"":6228,""ii"":3690,""jj"":1101,""kk"":-232,""ll"":65}]}";
 DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new 

 DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(JsonClass));

 MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result));
 JsonClass data= (JsonClass)serializer.ReadObject(memStream);
```

I've also tried with NewtonsoftJson library and it's the same:

```
var data= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonClass>(result);
```

What am I doign wrong?
Thank you very much!

Comment: What doesn't work? What error message do you get or exception? Why don't you use JSON.Net? It is much easier.

Comment: please show the errors you get when running the code

Comment: I've updated the question. I don't receive any error. The problem is that serialization result (data variable) is null when I use string from Web service. Is there any way to see if there is a error? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i checked the code... and i too faced the same kind of issue..
the return types in my code for the dataContract was not proper

```
public string ts { get; set; }
```

here the "ts" return type is string .but ,i doubt its date time.
for reference for serialization [click here to view json documentaion](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html)

and here is [example for json similar like yours which helped me](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/272335/JSON-Serialization-and-Deserialization-in-ASP-NET)
i hope my comment would help you :)